# my INotifypropertyChanged doesnt work in my Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, inotifypropertychanged

I need to notify when my SeekBar Progress property changed!
I created my SeekBar and override progress property!
but it doesnt work!

```
public class MySeekBar : SeekBar,INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MySeekBar(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public override int Progress 
    { 
      get => base.Progress;
      set { base.Progress = value; OnPropertyChange(); }  
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        var change = PropertyChanged;
        if (change != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you add the place where you actually bind to `Progress` and where the relevant `BindingContext` set? (and why do you create a new `MainActivity` there? it's nowhere used

Comment: What library are you using for the binding? As woellij indicated, can you show the binding code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something doesn't add up in your project. If you're using layouts then maybe you forgot to change the SeekBar class to MySeekBar? Plus you're missing some needed constructors for layouts. As for the implementation I probably would not override the property as the below works fine for me.

```
public class MySeekBar : SeekBar, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MySeekBar(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public MySeekBar(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base (context,attrs)    
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public MySeekBar(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base (context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) => 
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Progress"));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Added in the layout (the base namespace is SeekB so the control should be seekb.MySeekBar).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <seekb.MySeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1" />
</LinearLayout>
```